# Emails are received as junk

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, dns, google-apps, amazon-route53

We have a client with a website hosted on AWS and he is using Google apps to send notification emails. These emails are marked as spam/junk.

We have set an SPF record as per Google's documentation. Clicking on view messege source I found `SPF:softfail`. From what I understand, setting up reverse DNS/PTR record can also help, but we have 2 production instances behind an ELB and we're not sure how to set that up as it doesn't have a public IP.

This is how our Route53 setup looks:

```
example.com       A      ALIAS ***.elb.amazonaws.com.  
example.com       MX     1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.  
example.com       TXT    "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"   
mail.example.com  CNAME  ghs.googlehosted.com
```

Comment: Where did you find `SPF=softfail` ?

Comment: By viewing the message source. I edited my post.

Comment: Are google apps used to send mail by authenticated access to smtp.gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the client was sending *all* of his emails through local smtp without using Google Apps. I've added his IP to the SPF record temporarily until he moves the emails over to go through google. We have also set a DKIM record.

PTR records and ELBs had nothing to do with it.